# AS3 x and y property precision

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, rendering, coordinates, precision

In ActionScript 3 (and IIRC 2), the x and y properties on a display object are always stored as multiples of 0.05.

so something like `obj.x = 66.6666` is the same as `obj.x = 66.65`

Most of the time, this doesn't matter. But sometimes I can end up with really slow-moving objects, eg 1 pixel per second. 1/60 (fps) = 0.017 pixels per frame. `obj.x += 0.017` will **never** actually change the x value, since it gets rounded to the nearest 0.05.
This forces me to override the x & y properties of a DisplayObject so that they are not rounded.

I can understand rounding coordinates to the nearest integral value for rendering. With a more advanced renderer, I can even understand rounding to some fraction representable in binary (eg 0.25). But 0.05 cannot be represented exactly in binary.

So why might it be that the creators of Flash decided to round to the nearest .05? It just seems like such an arbitrary number to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [Wikipedia article on Twips](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twip):

> Flash internally calculates anything
>   that uses pixels with twips (or 1/20
>   of a pixel). Sprites, movie clips and
>   any other object on the stage are
>   positioned with twips. As a result,
>   the coordinates of (for example)
>   sprites are always multiples of 0.05
>   (i.e. 1/20).(i.e. 1/20).

A workaround would be to store the co-ordinates in a Number, and then assign it to the displayobject's properties.

Comment: ok, but my question is more about what the advantage of using multiples of .05 is.

Comment: According to the SWF file format specs, "Twips are a good compromise between size and precision. They provide sub-pixel accuracy for zooming and precise placement of objects, while consuming very few bits per coordinate."

Comment: Was this answer not what you were looking for?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the comment. That comment did answer my question.

Comment: Note that the precision applies before the transform matrix acts, so you can't draw something shorter or smaller than 0.05 pixels and then apply a big scale factor to it.

Answer (score 5):

Even better, precision is different for other properties of DisplayObject... consider following code:

```
var tmp:Number = 1/17;
var s:Sprite = new Sprite();
s.scaleX = tmp;
s.scaleY = tmp;
s.x = tmp;
s.y = tmp;
s.rotation = tmp;
trace(tmp);
trace(s.scaleX);
trace(s.scaleY);
trace(s.x);
trace(s.y);
trace(s.rotation);
```

it will output

```
0.058823529411764705
0.0588235294117647
0.0588235294117647
0.05
0.05
0.058823529411764705
```

which means that rotation is stored in Number precision, x and y in twips (multiple of 0.05) and scaleX and scaleY are stored in precision that is close to Number but a bit less (maybe exactly one bit less?)

Comment: That's sad to find out, and it's ridiculous.  Numbers should be stored as Number; this arbitrary rounding is just asking for scripting troubles, such as cumulative errors when transforming coordinates, and seriously, one BIT less precision for scaling?  It's like someone purposely sabotaged the system.  It's like "Oh, that's a Number, so I can do a calculation with it, except, no, you can't, because it's rounded under the hood without warning."